# Como adicionar uma classe em elementos html de uma string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O cenário é o seguinte: Eu monto dinamicamente um html. Depois que o html é gerado fica +/- assim:

```
var templateHtml = "<div class='bola'>Bola 1</div><div class='bola'>Bola 2</div><div class='casa'>Casa 1</div>";
```

Eu gostaria de adicionar a classe "futebol" em todas as divs com a classe "bola".

Tentei assim:

```
templateHtml = $(templateHtml).find(".bola").addClass("futebol");
```

Mas não funcionou....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua a chamada do método `find` por `filter`.

```
templateHtml = $(templateHtml).filter(".bola").addClass("futebol");
```

O `filter` filtra os elementos selecionados e o `find` procura dentro dos mesmos. O que acontece é que quando você passa o html como uma string os elementos selecionados são os que estão na primeira camada.

Por exemplo:

```
console.log($("<div id='div1'></div><div id='div2'></div>")); // [div#div1, div#div2]

// com a sua variável
console.log($(templateHtml)); // [div.bola, div.bola, div.casa]
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Mas por que com filter retorna o html e com o find não? Não entendi isso ainda.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Editei a resposta. Espero que tenha ficado mais clara =)